# Mongoose save working in app but not in Mocha

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocha.js

I'm trying to write some basic unit tests for a project I'm working on as a learning experience and have run into something that has me stumped.

Basically, I can run the code below in a standalone node application and the code creates the new DB and inserts the record as expected.  If I then take the same code and run it in a mocha test in node, I see mongod report a new connection, but no DB is created and no record is inserted (and no error is reported).

Any ideas what is going on (the mongoose code is pulled directly from the mongoose website).

Standalone Node App (server.js)

```
var mg = require( 'mongoose' );

mg.connect( 'mongodb://localhost/cat_test' );

var Cat = mg.model( 'Cat', { name: String } );
var kitty = new Cat({ name: 'Zildjian' });
kitty.save( function( err ){
    if ( err ){
        console.log( err );
    }
    process.exit();
});
```

Mocha Test (test.js)

```
describe( 'Saving models', function(){
    it( 'Should allow models to be saved to the database', function(){
        var mg = require( 'mongoose' );

        mg.connect( 'mongodb://localhost/cat_test' );

        var Cat = mg.model( 'Cat', { name: String } );
        var kitty = new Cat({ name: 'Zildjian' });
        kitty.save( function( err ){
            if ( err ){
                console.log( err );
            }
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Thoughts?  I'm guessing it's something very obvious that I'm overlooking but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out -

I needed to add the done parameter to the it call -

Mocha Test - revised

```
// The parameter below was left off before, which caused the test to run without
// waiting for results.
describe( 'Saving models', function( done ){
    it( 'Should allow models to be saved to the database', function(){
        var mg = require( 'mongoose' );

        mg.connect( 'mongodb://localhost/cat_test' );

        var Cat = mg.model( 'Cat', { name: String } );
        var kitty = new Cat({ name: 'Zildjian' });
        kitty.save( function( err ){
            if ( err ){
                console.log( err );
            }
            done();
        });
    });
});
```